# SEO on site temporarily redirected, then re-enabled

Tags: seo

I have a site which was performing well in the search engines - I wanted to redevelop the site, so in the interim period I set up a redirect from my site to my parent company's site (which has a small section relating to my services). Fairly quickly, this section of the parent site inherited my seo ranking, backlinks etc, which is fine and is what I expected. However, I now have a new site ready and plan to remove the redirect - do you know how this is likely to affect my site? Many thanks

Comment: Kinda the wrong time to ask don't you think? Shouldn't this have been considered *before* making such a change?

Answer (score 2):

If the content or urls have changed much then you will be starting from scratch.

However you can boost how quickly your site rises by taking advantage of existing links.  Check 404 logs and make sure to redirect incoming urls to **relevent** pages (not just your homepage)

Also if you can redirect those pages from the parent company back to the equivalent page in your new site you can transfer some rep back.